# Dual Screen with res wider than 1680px in Fedora 14

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, multi-monitor

I want to work in dual-screen mode with the monitors not mirroring, but extending each other, and I want the total resolution to be 3360x1050. When I try to apply dual-screen (that is, uncheck "Same image in all monitors" option) it says "required virtual size 3360x1050 does not fit available size 1680x1680".

Additionally, when I try to detect my monitors, both are pink monitors; that is, the monitors seem to not be detected as separate monitors.

So the question seems to be two-fold:

- How do I detect the monitors as separate monitors?

and

- How do I increase the available size?

Comment: Video card? Driver? Logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dual head setups require declaring the maximum display size in the Xorg configuration file, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. [Create this file](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_xorg.conf) by running `Xorg -configure` as root (or `Xorg :1 -configure` if you already have a GUI running). Copy the generated configuration to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, then make the desired modifications.

In the `Screen` section, you need to declare a display with a total size of at least 3360 by 1050. The `Screen` section might look like this:

```
Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Configured Screen"
        Device          "Configured Device"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth           8
                Virtual         3360 1050
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth           24
                Virtual         3360 1050
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: thx, it solved it perfectly.